# Repair URL using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, urlparse

There is a big file. Each line of this file is URL typed in by human so there can be different problems like missing `http` missing `www` etc.

Is there a Python module which can repair those urls? I've tried `url_fix` from `werkzeug.urls` but it is not exactly what I'm searching for.

```
www.example.com >> http://www.example.com/
```

Of course that there can't be method which can repair every possible mistake but I'm looking for repairing most common mistakes.

Have you any advice?

EDIT: According to  Peter Wood's comment, let's presume that URL has to contain `www`. In my case, those are eshop URLs.

Comment: Missing `www` isn't necessarily a mistake.